# Finding out the no. of bar since MACD Line has crossed up / down Signal Line in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I have written this routine to find out the no of bars since the MACD Line has crossed up or down the Signal Line. This supports multiple time frames so takes the resolution as a parameter.

It doesn't give me the right result! Neither I see anything wrong in the logic!
A brief on the logic:

1. First checking if the MACD Line is above or below Signal line.
2. Based on that initialize y to +1 / -1 to give back to the calling function
3. Then increment the x inside an iteration so we keep going back into the past till the MACD Line crosses the Signal Line.
4. Capture the x value and send back to the calling function so to say index count since the cross had happened...

I felt this is something basic and essential and was surprised not to see anything in the community / internet! Don't want to reinvent the wheel!

If there is something available out there for this specific requirement please let me know...else help me with this dysfunctional logic!

Appreciate your time and help!

```
macd_index(_res)=>
    [macdline_2452_res, signalLine_2452_res, histLine_2452_res] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _res, ta.macd(close, 24, 52, 9), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    
    x = 0
    y = 1
    
    if( macdline_2452_res[x] > signalLine_2452_res[x])
        y := 1
        while macdline_2452_res[x] > signalLine_2452_res[x]
            x:= x+1
    else
        if( macdline_2452_res[x] < signalLine_2452_res[x])
            y := -1
            while macdline_2452_res[x] < signalLine_2452_res[x]
                x:= x+1
    [x,y]
```

Comment: have you tried using `barssince(crossover(macd,signal))` , in this code it will return integer value telling you the number of bars it has been since macd crossed over signal line

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. My bad I didn't scan well the "ta" library. I have one more question to top it up:

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. My bad.. I didn't scan well the "ta" library. 
I have a follow up question:
I use these functions in a routine that supports multiple time frames. 
Couple of lines pasted here for your reference.

[macdline, signalLine, histLine] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _res, ta.macd(close, 24, 52, 9), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
ta.barssince(ta.crossover(macdline,signalLine))
(continuing in the next comment)

Comment: Now this returns the no. of bars based on the time frame of the underlying chart. So I get ~360 when I am expecting ~15 for a 2H timeframe. Because I embedded this in a chart whose time frame is 5m and there are 24 5 min bars in each hour. Is there a way, I could get the same no. of bars as the time frame of MACD / Signal Line, in this case no. of 2H bars.

Hope i made my question clear enough!

Again highly appreciate your help on this!